# how is maxrate used in FFMPEG when converting?

Tags: ffmpeg

I met a problem when converting video stream into mpeg2 format with specified max bitrate in FFMPEG.

The input file has a high bitrate of about 40Mbps (resolution is 720P),

what I want to archive is to get a mpeg video of max bit rate of 9Mbps (keep same resolution)

But when I used

```
ffmpeg.exe -i Untitled720P.mp4 -c:v mpeg2video -c:a ac3 -r 25 -pix_fmt yuv420p -g 15 -       
b:v 6000000 -maxrate 9000000 -minrate 0 -bufsize 1835008 -packetsize 2048 -muxrate 
10080000 -b:a 448000 -ar 48000 manual.mpg
```

there came out lots warnings of "buffer underflow", and the generated file has an overall bitrate of 29.7Mbps although 9000k is specified to be max.

This generated mpeg video, when played in VLC player, stopped somewhere.

So I want to know, if there's any other argument I can use to force ffmpeg to generate an output which strictly stays below the specified max bitrate?

Great thanks

Comment: Should really be on Super User

Comment: @PreetSangha In close/flag you can vote to migrate the question to [su] instead of simply closing it.

Comment: The complete ffmpeg console output is missing.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard - Sorry I must have done it wrong - normally I do choose it correctly.